# Looking for a way to not show duped rows using a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, rows

```
SELECT 
    AEC.gwd_people.id_people,
    AEC.gwd_people.uid_people, 
    AEC.gwd_people.cod_people,
    AEC.gwd_people.name_people, 
    AEC.gwd_people.surname_people,
    AEC.gwd_people.email, 
    AEC.gwd_people.people_status, 
    AEC.gwd_people.people_type,
    AEC.gwd_people.facility_reference,
    AEC.gwd_people.sc_id_sap,
    AEC.gwd_people.c_id_sap,
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_people, 
    AEC.gwd_people.cod_sector,
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_sector,
    AEC.gwd_people.cod_org_sector,
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_org_sector,
    AEC.gwd_people.cod_company,
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_company, 
    AEC.gwd_people.cod_company_sap,
    AEC.gwd_people.cod_department,
    AEC.gwd_department.descr_department,
    AEC.gwd_people.cod_subdepartment,
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_subdepartment, 
    AEC.gwd_people.cod_cdc,
    AEC.gwd_cost_center.descr_cdc,
    AEC.gwd_people.cod_category_job,
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_category_job,
    AEC.gwd_people.cod_people_job,
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_people_job, 
    AEC.gwd_people.cod_position,
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_position,
    AEC.gwd_people.uohr,
    AEC.gwd_people.qual_contract,
    AEC.gwd_people.level_position,
    AEC.gwd_people.cod_manager, 
    AEC.gwd_people.cod_validator,
    AEC.gwd_people.cod_country,
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_country,
    AEC.gwd_people.cod_region_area,
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_region_area,
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_city, 
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_site,
    AEC.gwd_people.address_1,
    AEC.gwd_people.address_2,
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_building,
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_room,
    AEC.gwd_people.validity_date, 
    AEC.aec_workstation.cod_workstation,
    AEC.aec_workstation.geometry,
    AEC.aec_workstation.drawing,
    AEC.gwd_people.tax_code,
    AEC.gwd_people.phone_1,
    AEC.gwd_people.phone_2,
    AEC.gwd_people.phone_3, 
    AEC.gwd_people.phone_4,
    AEC.gwd_people.ext_email_1,
    AEC.gwd_people.flagvip,
    AEC.gwd_people.hiring_date,
    AEC.gwd_people.cease_date,
    AEC.gwd_people.cid_resp_liv_1,
    AEC.gwd_people.cid_resp_liv_2, 
    AEC.gwd_people.id_resp,
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_resp, 
    AEC.gwd_people.id_ref,
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_ref, 
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_ext_people,
    AEC.gwd_people.ext_email_2,
    AEC.gwd_people.descr_sede, 
        (CASE WHEN AEC.aec_r_workstation_people.cod_people IS NULL
          THEN AEC.gwd_people.idplan
          ELSE NULL
          END) AS idplan,
        (CASE WHEN AEC.aec_r_workstation_people.cod_people IS NOT NULL 
          THEN SUBSTRING(AEC.aec_workstation.cod_workstation, 5, 7)
           ELSE NULL
           END) AS idplan_wrkst,
        (CASE WHEN AEC.aec_r_workstation_people.cod_people IS NULL 
          THEN AEC.view_iam_r_unitp_building.IDEDIFICIO
           ELSE NULL
           END) AS cod_building,
        (CASE WHEN AEC.aec_r_workstation_people.cod_people IS NOT NULL 
          THEN SUBSTRING(AEC.aec_workstation.cod_workstation, 5, 3)
           ELSE NULL
           END) AS cod_building_wrkst,
        (CASE WHEN AEC.aec_r_workstation_people.cod_people IS NOT NULL 
          THEN AEC.aec_workstation.id_room
           ELSE NULL
           END) AS id_room_wrkst,
        (CASE WHEN AEC.aec_r_workstation_people.cod_people IS NOT NULL
          THEN AEC.aec_workstation.id_room
           ELSE NULL
           END) AS id_room_wrkst2
FROM AEC.gwd_people
 LEFT OUTER JOIN AEC.view_iam_r_unitp_building ON 
 AEC.view_iam_r_unitp_building.IDUNITPROD = AEC.gwd_people.cod_sector
 LEFT OUTER JOIN AEC.aec_r_workstation_people ON AEC.gwd_people.cod_people = 
 AEC.aec_r_workstation_people.cod_people
 LEFT OUTER JOIN AEC.aec_workstation ON AEC.aec_workstation.cod_workstation 
 = AEC.aec_r_workstation_people.cod_workstation
 LEFT OUTER JOIN AEC.gwd_department ON AEC.gwd_department.cod_department = 
 AEC.gwd_people.cod_department
 LEFT OUTER JOIN AEC.gwd_cost_center ON AEC.gwd_cost_center.cod_cost_center 
 = AEC.gwd_people.cod_cdc
```

This is my query and I'm using SQL Server 13, it returns 6752 rows, 44 of them are duped. I've tried everything I know to avoid showing those duped entries but I'm out of ideas, so I'm looking for some helpful tips :-) One of the biggest problem is taht all fields are necessary, so I can't get rid of "AEC.aec_workstation.geometry" that causes problems with SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: On a sidenote: Many outer joins. Do you really expect people not belonging to a department for instance? Use inner joins where appropriate. Only outer join when necessary.

Comment: Another sidenote: Table aliases can make a query much more readable (e.g. `FROM aec.gwd_people p JOIN aec.gwd_department d on d.cod_department = p.cod_department`).

Comment: Have you considered putting the word `DISTINCT` after the word `SELECT`?

Answer (score 1):

Find a PK value from your first table that's returning a duplicate row and start with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(1)
FROM 
    AEC.gwd_people
WHERE
    AEC.gwd_people.PrimaryKeyColumn = 'SomeValue'
```

Now start adding joins one by one, checking the result of the `COUNT(1)` each time:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(1)
FROM 
    AEC.gwd_people
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AEC.view_iam_r_unitp_building ON AEC.view_iam_r_unitp_building.IDUNITPROD = AEC.gwd_people.cod_sector
WHERE
    AEC.gwd_people.PrimaryKeyColumn = 'SomeValue'
```

And then...

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(1)
FROM 
    AEC.gwd_people
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AEC.view_iam_r_unitp_building ON AEC.view_iam_r_unitp_building.IDUNITPROD = AEC.gwd_people.cod_sector
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AEC.aec_r_workstation_people ON AEC.gwd_people.cod_people = AEC.aec_r_workstation_people.cod_people
WHERE
    AEC.gwd_people.PrimaryKeyColumn = 'SomeValue'
```

Until you see the amount of rows jump up when you don't expect it to. You are most likely:

- Not considering that duplicate rows can be expected.
- Missing another join column on a table.
- Having duplicate rows on a table.

... or combination of these.

Comment: On a sidenote: Use `COUNT(*)` (i.e. count rows) rather than `COUNT(1)` (i.e. count rows for which a generated 1 would not be null). Don't rely on the DBMS's optimizer to see through this. If it literally did what you asked for, it would do a lot more work when necessary. Only use `COUNT(<expression>)` where appropriate.

Comment: Anyway, I like your answer suggesting to simply drill down until the culprit is found. As to the primary key: My guess is that `cod_people` is the table's unique key.

Answer (score 0):

Your table design makes it a bit hard to understand their relations. This is what it looks like to me:

```
gwd_department  {1:n}  gwd_people
gwd_people      {m:n}  aec_workstation
gwd_people      {m:n}  view_iam_r_unitp_building
gwd_people      {?:n}  gwd_cost_center
```

So for a person linked to 3 aec_workstations and 4 view_iam_r_unitp_buildings, you'd produce 3 x 4 = 12 result rows. Is there no further relation between an aec_workstation and a view_iam_r_unitp_building? If not, then why do you combine them in your query?

I don't know whether cod_cdc is supposed to be short for cod_cost_center or something different. If this is an m:n relation, too, you are doing the same thing again with gwd_cost_center related to aec_workstation and view_iam_r_unitp_building.

Having said this: Either add the missing criteria or ask yourself what you want to select after all.